# Tkinter/Canvas-based kiosk-like program for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tkinter-canvas, kiosk

I would like run a Python program on a Raspberry Pi (or, for that matter, any Unix/Linux-based computer) that effectively turns the entire screen into a canvas and allows me to draw text and graphics objects on it in real time.  I ideally want this to also automatically conceal everything else on the desktop and eliminate the window frame and task bar, similar to playing a video in full screen mode (with ESC to exit).

My research so far suggests that Tkinter/Canvas would be the simplest solution. But while I have found examples online that accomplish *part* of what I describe above, I haven't been able to put the pieces together in a form that does it all.  It doesn't help that I have no prior experience with Tkinter.

If someone can point me to a minimal working example of the setup described, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: get any example with Canvas and add option `-fullscreen` (and maybe `-topmost`) to main window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minimal example. It create fullscreen window, without borders, always on top
so you can't toggle to other window, ie. to console to kill program.

You can close it by pressing `ESC` but I add function to close after 5 second if `ESC` will not work :)

It draws red oval on full screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def on_escape(event=None):
    print("escaped")
    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# --- fullscreen ---

#root.overrideredirect(True)  # sometimes it is needed to toggle fullscreen
                              # but then window doesn't get events from system
#root.overrideredirect(False) # so you have to set it back

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True) # run fullscreen
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True) # keep on top
#root.focus_set() # set focus on window

# --- closing methods ---

# close window with key `ESC`
root.bind("<Escape>", on_escape)

# close window after 5s if `ESC` will not work
root.after(5000, root.destroy) 

# --- canvas ---

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

canvas.create_oval((0, 0, screen_width, screen_height), fill='red', outline='')

# --- start ---

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The solution suggested by furas is extremely close. I had to uncomment the commented lines for it to actually go full screen on my Mac.  But I still had to click on the window to set focus, despite the root.focus_set() statement.  Not sure why.  Since I want to be able to launch the program without user intervention, this is kind of important.  If that last bit can get solved, then I'll mark the solution as solved.

Comment: I don't use Mac so I can't help. But it works on my Linux Mint without problems.

Comment: maybe if you run `focus_set()` with delay using `after()` then maybe it will work - but I don't use Mac to test it.

Comment: Marking as 'solved' since my problem with focus may be Mac-specific.